# Intercept background audio stream on iOS

Tags: ios

Is it possible for an iOS app to intercept the background audio stream that's playing?

I'd like to do some visualization for whatever audio is currently playing whether it's iTunes, Spotify, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get access to this, actually.

It's possible to play music with an app that remains in the background when the app isn't active, but you can't get access to another app's audio stream.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2021?

Comment: I don't know. Twitch's streaming app seems to be able to send the whole screen plus audio, so maybe there's a way to do it now.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look into it, perhaps post another question and report back here.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is possible now, only if another app subscribes to [InterApp Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/InterAppAudioSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) or Audiobus.

Consolidated from other SO answers for clarity:

[Is there a way to intercept audio output from within your app to display back an audio visualizer on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061264/is-there-a-way-to-intercept-audio-output-from-within-your-app-to-display-back-an)

[Intercept/modify audio stream on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676695/intercept-modify-audio-stream-on-ios)