# Intercept/modify audio stream on iOS

Tags: ios, audio

I am looking at the feasibility of getting the current raw audio stream playing and do stuff with it such as stream it over Bluetooth or equalize it, etc. Is there any way to do this in iOS 8?

For example: apps such as Pandora/Spotify are playing music and I want to access the audio they are playing.

Answer (score 0):

To process audio from another app, that app needs to participate in [Inter-App Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/InterAppAudioSuite/Introduction/Intro.html).

I don't know if your example apps do that.

Comment: I stumbled across that too. It would seem there is no way to get any audio playing but rather only apps that support inter-app audio. Doesn't look like iTunes/Pandora/Spotify support this.