# Is there a way to intercept audio output from within your app to display back an audio visualizer on iOS?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, linphone

We're currently using [Linphone](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone) library to make VOIP calls and they have their own solution for audio playback. However, we would like to display a visualizer for the audio that Linphone is outputting from within our own app. Is there a way that we can intercept this data (maybe through sample buffering) in order to draw up audio waves/volume meter in the user interface?

AVAudioPlayer or AVPlayer is out of the question since we do not have access to those objects. Is there a solution in place for AVAudioSession or in CoreAudio?

Comment: It's not possible if the other app doesn't allow it. Not sure why you were downvoted though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if the audio output app is exporting the audio data using Inter-App-audio or Audiobus.  Otherwise the iOS security sandbox will hide that audio output from your app.

Comment: Can you give some specifics? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340947/avaudiosession-how-do-i-listen-to-the-devices-output