# how to use xcrun simctl io to pipe and record an iOS audio stream

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, xcrun, simctl

My iOS app writes a stereo audio stream into a circular buffer at 44.1KHz and outputs successfully to either simulator or iOS device. I want to capture the audio stream while the app is running in Xcode and do it without altering the code or converting the stream to an analogue signal.

Initially I tried using SoundFlower with Audacity and Quicktime. Both work with audio from the internal microphone but unfortunately capture ambient noise and with `Soundflower(2ch)` input selected no signal activity appears in the monitor on either Audacity or Quicktime.

I am now trying to create an ogg file by capturing a digital audio stream using terminal e.g. copying the stream and piping the copy into a file, a bit [like this Linux solution](https://jordilin.wordpress.com/2006/07/28/howto-recording-audio-from-the-command-line/)

```
       arecord -f cd -t raw | oggenc – -r -o out.ogg
```

The following Unix command line fails to capture audio when it records video according to this [Radar community bug report submitted Feb 2018](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4929896522448896).

```
       xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo my video.mp4
```

I have set up [command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36726612/2348597) so audio data sent from Xcode to the simulator can be captured. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29757645/2348597) (*from 2015*) says it is not possible to intercept a background audio stream from another app. But does anyone know a way to pipe an audio stream into a file using `xcrun simctl io` ?